# Terminology for $\frac{n+1}{m+2}$ estimator

Tags: probability, bayesian

A long time ago I read about a simplistic estimator for the probability of a binary outcome (say 1 or 0) which takes the form

$$P = \dfrac{n+1}{m+2}$$

where $n$ is the number of "successes" while $m$ is the number of attempts.

So, if you have no information on which binary outcome is more likely ($n = m = 0$), you are forced to assume they're equally likely, each with $P = 0.5$.

If your first attempt has an outcome of $0$, you can then adjust your expected probability of the next attempt also being $0$ to $P_0 = \dfrac{1 + 1}{1 + 2} = \dfrac{2}{3}$.

After the second attempt also outputs $0$, you get $P_0 = \dfrac34$. When your third attempt outputs $1$, it becomes $P_0 = \dfrac35$, etc.

What is this type of estimate (either generally or this specific equation) called? I remembered it as a Bayesian estimator (it certainly describes Bayesian thinking), but after Googling a bit I didn't find anything like this.

Comment: What about "Wasabian estimator"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde should I take that to mean this isn't a thing? I'm sure I didn't make this up, I know I read about this somewhere. (Though it might've been from someone as uneducated as myself...)

Comment: Are you refering to Laplace smoothing (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108797/in-naive-bayes-why-bother-with-laplace-smoothing-when-we-have-unknown-words-in) ?

Comment: Maybe it should be called the [sunrise estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem).

Comment: @J.G. close, but no cigar. So close, though, that it linked to the correct answer: it's simply the statement of the [rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession).

Comment: @Wasabi 1) Yes, Laplace already discussed it 2) As I am not native English speaker, what do you mean by "no cigar" (is it a classical expression for a "reward" ?) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie "close but no cigar" is an English expression, and you're correct: you got close, but you don't deserve to smoke a cigar to celebrate.

Comment: @Wasabi Thanks to you, I have a (+1) in my knowledge of English idiosyncrasies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Bayesian LMS (least mean squares) estimator.

Let's consider coin tossing experiment with probability of Heads $\Theta$ (random variable in Bayesian setup); the number of successes in $n$ tosses is random variable $M$.

We assume that prior is uniform, $\Theta\sim U[0,1]$; then posterior has beta distribution, and the estimator $\widehat{\Theta}$ is

$$\widehat{\Theta}=\mathbb{E}[\Theta|M=m]=\frac{m+1}{n+2}$$

The derivation can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XS33yIOtEew)

Answer (score 1):

As was discussed in the comments, this estimator arises in the [sunrise problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem), is derived as the [rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession), and may be called the Laplace-Bayes estimator.